# correct way to implement a custom popup window? Activity vs. Dialog vs. AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-alertdialog

My app contains an activity, call it activity A, that displays details (title, author, brief summary etc.) of a given book. The TextView that holds brief summary is clickable and leads to a popup window that displays the extended summary of the book.

- Option1: implement the popup window as a new Activity (seems an overkill)
- Option2: implement it as an instance of the Dialog class with a custom layout (simply discouraged)
- Option3: implement it as an instance of the AlertDialog class with a custom layout (looks just wrong)

What is the "correct" way to implement a simple popup window and why?

Here is the xml file of the popup window

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fefefe"
android:padding="16dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_book_summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#555555"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_dismiss_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/brown_btn"
        android:text="@string/btn_close"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why option #2 is discouraged? Just because it's a `Dialog` instead of a `DialogFragment`? Personally, I am not a fan of modal/popup windows, so I would try and test a different UI altogether.

Comment: Please, read the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) on dialogs. It's worth a **deep read**.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli in the reference page it says: "The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following subclasses[...]"

Comment: @kouretinho right, sorry, I misunderstood what you intended. So, since the very same reference page you cite says "you should use a `DialogFragment` as a container for your dialog", what about using it? Being a `Fragment`, it's quite easy to provide it with its own UI, inflated from the XML document you already have.

Comment: thanks for all the feedback @GiulioPiancastelli. It seems that DialogFragments are indeed the best way to go forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think will better to use option #2 or #3. If you will just show additional content to user and user will not interact with views in Dialog - than #3 is best choice, I think. Instead (for example, if you will have complex layout with additional buttons, etc) use #2.

PS: also, the modern way - to use DialogFragment instead of Dialogs.

Comment: ok, so the verdict is first "avoid Activities" and second "use inflated Dialogs" (DialogFragments more precisely). Thx @Dimmerg. Answer accepted.